# HTMLInputElement when summing form values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I'm trying to get form fields total sum value, but instead this I'm  `[object HTMLInputElement]2552`.. numbers is form fields values (not summed). What is wrong here?

```
function update() {
     var sum = 0;
      $("#formaa div.row").each(function(i,o){
        total = parseInt($(o).find(".ki").val(), 10) * parseInt($(o).find(".ka").val(), 10);
             if(!isNaN(total) && total.length!=0) {
                     $(o).find("[name=suma]").val(total);
                    suma += total;
                }
      });
      $("#suma").val(suma);
    }
```

Comment: Does `var total = parseInt($(o).find(".ki")[0].val(), 10) * parseInt($(o).find(".ka")[0].val(), 10);` work?

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff yes it work fine

Comment: With that code, does it still output `[object HTMLInputElement]`?

Comment: total returns sum values of each products seperately and `suma += total` should return summed total values, but I'm getting `[object HTMLInputElement]` instead of this.

Comment: Try using this code: http://shaquin.tk/tests/temp1.txt. I assume you are using IE, because in IE, every element is available as a variable of its name, so `suma += total;` is trying to add `total` to the element `suma`. This will probably be fixed by using `suma_val` instead of `suma` for the variable.

Comment: @Shaquin Trifonoff I'm using Chrome, tried on Firefox also, your code always showing 0 in #suma field

Comment: I've found a problem! All what I need to do is change #suma form field into some other name, and its working

Comment: If you have solved the problem, consider posting your own answer. See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions and http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/.